# Getting latitude-longitudes from tiff and world file

Tags: qgis, remote-sensing, geotiff-tiff

I have downloaded Version 4 DMSP-OLS from [here](http://ngdc.noaa.gov/eog/dmsp/downloadV4composites.html), which is a bunch of tiff files with their world files. I would now like to crop an area specified by bottom left and top right lat-long points.

I downloaded QGIS, but couldn't get it to read the world file.

Googling around, I found some tools that convert tiff file and world file to Geotiff, but they were for Windows and I am on a Mac.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the latest version of QGIS, it has no problem reading and displaying the tif files. You need to extract the .tif.gz files to .tif in advance using your operating systems tools. Then add the .tif to the canvas:

[image]

You can extract a subregion with `Raster -> Clipper` by dragging a rectangle on the screen, or specifying a bounding box in the map units (degrees).

Comment: Is there any way to specify the bounding box using lat long values?

Comment: Since the map is in degrees, you can enter the lat long values directly into the input form. I prefer to drag a box, then change the values to those I want.